# MSBuildExtensionsPath32 is not resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, msbuild

I am trying to use C:\Prpgram Files (x86) on X64 machine and C:\Program Files on X86 machine in my build to refer to a VBA path like blow

I use the following path in my Project ->Properties -> C++ -> Additional Include Directrories

C:\$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\VBA6SDK\include

But I get compilation errors on a X86 machine since It cant find some header files located at 
C:\Program Files\VBA6SDK\include

if I replace $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) with "program files" no issues.

This is a MFC project that I am building using VS2010.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) property normally contains "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild".  The directory where MSBuild extensions are stored.

This of course has nothing to do with the VBA6SDK you are trying to use so the property is not very useful.  You can use `$(ProgramFiles)` to use the system environment variable, it will be C:\Program Files (x86) on a 64-bit English operating system for the 32-bit toolchains.  Don't prefix with C:\

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans. When I type echo %ProgramFiles% on a command prompt on 64 bit machine, it seems to be C:\Program Files . Since VS2010 is a 32 bit app, it will be C:\Program Files (x86) ? How do I check this on a command prompt ?

Comment: Nevermind I found out myeslf :) If I run the command prompt from Syswow64 folder and echo %ProgramFiles% it does print C:\Program Files (x86)